# Javascript - Refactor a class splitting it by concepts

Tags: javascript, oop, refactoring

I am trying to refactor (splitting by concepts) the following class:

```
import myService from "./myService"

...

export default function MyService() {
  if (!isInstantiated) {
    myService.configurate(configuration);

    // Initialize Auth and Database
    this.auth = myService.auth(); // myService.auth() has to be performed after myService.configurate()
    this.database = myService.database(); // myService.database() has to be performed after myService.configurate()

    isInstantiated = true;
  }
}

MyService.prototype.methodAssociatedWithAuthConcept = function () {
  ...
};

... more mothods associated with the "Auth" concept

MyService.prototype.methodAssociatedWithDatabaseConcept = function (email, password) {
  ...
};

... more mothods associated with the "Database" concept
```

In a future, this class will be really big, so splitting it into other classes "Auth" and "Database" is my best option, but... `myService.auth()` and `myService.database()` has to be performed when `myService.configurate(configuration)` is done in the **MyService constructor's singleton**.

And, also, I have to be able to access Auth class and Database class from MyService class, instantiating them in the MyService singleton, in order to do:

```
const myServiceObj = new MyService();
myServiceObj.database.someMethodAssociatedWithDatabaseConcept();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That sound like you need a factory.

Outsource your database and auth. Then write a factory that implements both of them on demand. Your factory can create a new constructor for every usecase. constructors are in fact just normal functions that call Object.create() and do some prototyping for you. Then they return the object created with Object.create(). But you can handle that totally by your own. So adding diffent calls in your constructor is easy.

- Give your factory standard methods for accessing auth and database.
- import your database and auth on demand
- export an new generated class with all functions you need for your database and/or auth